# Is it possible to use MTOM in reponse of CXF RESTful Web Service

Tags: rest, cxf, mtom

I'm using **CXF 2.2.12** library for my Web Services.

Is it possible to use **MTOM** (*Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism*)
in **RESTful** response?

Would appreciate any links to docs/tutorials regarding this. Thanx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MTOM is specific to SOAP so I would argue that it is incompatible with a RESTful architecture.  However, HTTP supports multi-part content naturally, so you can do everything that MTOM does in HTTP directly.

If you really wanted you could use [XOP](http://www.w3.org/TR/xop10/) for packaging your multi-part content like MTOM does, but it really isn't necessary.

MTOM is solving a problem that HTTP already solved.

Comment: Thanx Darrel for quick response! If I understood correctly: e.g. I'm sending PDF file as service response, RESTful is already efficient since it's using HTTP, and there is no need for SOAP MTOM for sending binary data back to the client. SOAP MTOM will not provide better performance, than RESTful?

Comment: @IgorB  If your HTTP client can handle GZip compression then you can GZip the PDF before sending it.