# Returning an image from a REST web service

Tags: web-services, rest, attachment

I need to return an image from my rest web service. How can I achieve this? Furthermore, What would be the best way to do that? Should I send a link to my image or return the image directly from my web service? The image to be returned to the client is confidential. Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a SOAP you can use MTOM to add your image in response. As you mentioned that you are using REST, following question may help you: 
[Is it possible to use MTOM in reponse of CXF RESTful Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790989/is-it-possible-to-use-mtom-in-reponse-of-cxf-restful-web-service)