# What is the difference of sending an image via JAX-WS or REST?

Tags: java, web-services, http, rest, jax-ws

I want to know the difference, advantages and disadvantages of these two web services. Imagine I want to send a big image file:

a) a RPC based webservice via JAX-WS using SOAP

b) a REST based webservice using HTTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP has a mechanism called Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (MTOM) that is used specifically for sending large binary data (e.g. images).

REST uses HTTP directly, which means that anything done with SOAP (and MTOM) can be done using REST. Look at this answer: [Is it possible to use MTOM in reponse of CXF RESTful Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790989/is-it-possible-to-use-mtom-in-reponse-of-cxf-restful-web-service)

Comment: That means SOAP is faster? Does it transfer one big package?

Comment: My bad, I edited the contents of the answer about REST. Its bit late over here.

Comment: In general, if need to use SOAP then use MTOM, which will come close to performance of REST. Otherwise use REST, since its faster.

Comment: so when use RPC SOAP or is it an older technique?

Comment: That depends if you need to use RPC (like SOAP) or REST (like RESTful). Both approaches are valid depending to requirements.